# Spells Battle at the ministry

Tags: harry-potter

Which spells did Voldemort and Dumbledore use at the battle of the ministry.

Voldi used avada and what red spell was it what dumbledore used?

The burning snake?

The Water bending?
[image: This spell?]

The glass bending?

Answer (score 1):

The book never mentioned any names of the spell as they both dueled non-verbally. Aside from Avada Kedavra, the other spells were never seen before or again.

More details here: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Duel_in_the_Ministry_Atrium

Comment: That sucks, but was Dumbledore using expelliarmus?

Comment: I am pretty sure that Dumbledore was using non-lethal spells. Voldemort said something along the lines "Not aiming to kill me? Above such brutality are you, Dumbledore?".